DNF Automatic (used on test boxes) not rebooting after updates?
I use DNF Automatic on some test and POC boxes to ensure they don't fall behind on security updates. There seems to be a few issues with dnf-automatic generally, in particularly with parts of the config failing silently, but I now have it to the point it is installing updates reliably on a weekly basis. However, whatever I try I can't seem to get a reboot to trigger afterwards. I've tried when-changed, when-needed(also with _ as well as - as this seems to be inconsistent between parameter name and setting), and with and without an associative reboot command, but whatever I do my boxes won't reboot post update.
Here is my config, it's pretty simple. Has anybody encountered any similar issue/know what the problem could be? Thanks in advance.
upgrade_type = security
upgrade_requirements_on_install = yes
download_updates = yes
apply_updates = yes
gpgcheck = 1
random_sleep = 2
reboot = when-changed
reboot_command = "shutdown -r +5 'Rebooting after applying package updates'

[emitters]
emit_via = motd[alexw@dcbutlpocglog5 dnf]$ locate dnf-autom

[REDACTED@dcbutlpocglog5 dnf]$ cat /etc/systemd/system/dnf-automatic.timer.d/override.conf
[Timer]
OnCalendar=
OnCalendar=Mon 05:00
RandomizedDelaySec=15m
Persistent=true

[REDACTED@dcbutlpocglog5 dnf]$ systemctl is-enabled dnf-automatic.timer
enabled


The reboot parameters were only implemented in RHEL/Alma 9, my test boxes are Alma 8.
